Properly scanning/editing Film with mirrorless camera
I am scanning film at home using a mirrorless camera. My results are lacklustre at best with colors being wonky, especially in the shadows. Especially photos that have a lot of negative space (night photography) usually turn out very bad. The histogram is very narrow (I know that’s to be expected) but there is hardly any information in the scans often times. In daylight photos the color of the sky is often off and so on.
I am not doing this for the first time and have tried a lot to fix this. My setup consists of:
Light panel: Raleno 192 Video Light CRI > 95
Filmholder: Valoi 360
Lens: pantax k 120mm macro f4
Camera: Fuji GFX100s
I know that watching videos and reading articles doesn’t equate to learning something, but I’ve spent a lot of time researching this and I’ve been trying to get my scans right for over a year now. Also the youtuber Kyle McDougall has basically the same setup and gets way better results. I am honestly at a loss here, so if anyone here that scans films like this themselves is willing to help me figure this out I would be very grateful.

What exposure and image capture setup are you using?  EG are you shooting RAW or JPG? Are you doing any post-processing? I assume you have some sort of tripod/mounting for your camera.

As you did not include any settings or a photo of how you take your images, I simply assume what could go wrong.
I assume that you are using you light panel without additional diffusion under your negatives holder and then have the camera on a tripod above the setup to take the image, resulting in a raw file.
Things to check:

Are you using constant settings aka manual mode? All sources you photograph should be already correctly exposed, so adding any auto setting in here will result in a huge variation of exposures in your images. So once the exposure is set, it should the same for all images, unless you change anything in the setup. Valoi actually recommends dialing in the exposure at +0.7 to +1 EV as you might be losing some light through the image (and probably because, dimming an image will do better for the dark parts regarding signal to noise)
Did you lock your color balance for the light you are using? Set light and camera to 5600k.
Are you getting additional light from the panel into your lens? Shining additional light from around the frame holder into you lens might influence overall contrast by flaring.
Have you made 100% sure (by taking a photo with the light panel switched off) that you are not getting ambient light in? If you are not getting a pitch black frame by this test, you are throwing the contrast off. If you are getting ambient light in, reduce ambient light. Switch off additional lamps, close curtains etc.
Can you elaborate what programs you are using for reverting the negatives to positives? With color negatives, it is not enough to simply invert the image. The photographer you mention uses Negative Lab Pro.
You might want to add some distance and additional diffusion to the light panel. A light panel with settable color temperature has at least 2 different color LEDs in the panel. Used as a light source, it evens out by distance. If you place something on the surface of the light, that might not be the case. You might end up with cooler and warmer colors identifiable in the shot.
Are you using fully mechanical shutter? Sometimes LED panels are casing problems with the electronic shutter, resulting in banding. As you are using a video panel, this should not be the case, but you could test anyways just to make sure.


this was a bit of a lazy post, I should have included photos of my setup and results, but forgive me, I'm new here :)

yes, everything is shot in manual mode. I have found that slightly adjusting exposure for very bright/dark scenes yields slightly better results. I am also sticking to 2/3 over exposed
I recently started to use 5300K instead of 5600K and I set my wb to the film base, so between the negatives on the film
I have not tried the darkness test, I will emplement that. Thank you! but I scan at night with all lights off, so there should be no other light



I have 3D printed a mask to cover my light panel and it has improved my results but not to the point I am happy with
I have tried Negative Lab Pro, VueScan, SIlverfast. Those programs are nice, but the results are not very good, especially compared to a lab scan. I also greatly dislike the blackbox like nature of those programs, since it limits my controll over the image. Also the price tag of 100 bucks is a bit hard to swallow. I use Lightroom to invert and then adjust the color curves so the histogram shows good overlap. This yields the best results so far, but still not amazing



I have a light panel that has a diffusion screen built in, so there are no individual lights visible at all. There is another diffusion screen built into the negative holder, and some distance between the negative and the diffusion screen, I don't think that's the issue
That's a good idea. I have been avoiding the mechanical shutter to reduce camera shake, since somtimes my exposure times go up to 1/4 s when the negative is very dense. Thank you for your extensive comment, it really means a lot!


Hi @jocka Please, don't be lazy ;) You can (and should) edit all this good information into your original question.

Generally speaking, even if you're using software like Vuescan, that actually knows how color negatives behave, white balance is up for interpretation.
I would get used to finding light and dark grey things (or at least you think they are grey and can adjust them later) in the scene and setting red green and blue at those points to the same brightness in curves.  Also often you want to end up with a slanted 's-curve' that gently rounds the shadows into black and the highlights into white to expand the contrast of the image to fit the contrast of the screen.
Expect this to easily take much longer than 'scanning'. There's a lot of iterative decisions and creative adjustment in processing scanned film.
Admittedly my workflow is very old, but at least Picture Window Pro is free now so a program with a very advanced curves window is easy to get ahold of.

I have noticed that the workflow is slower then just scanning. And there are a lot of iterative decisions, but that is exactly what I want to avoid. I don't want to decide on an image by image basis how the photo should look like, since the film should decide that for me

@jocka Philosophically you may have chosen the wrong tool then.  You probably want a piece of software or equipment that knows how your workflow operates and can make intelligent guesses on what you want.  Mini-labs can do scans with automatic settings like this.  Vuescan can be this (auto levels or click-to-select grey) for an Epson or film scanner, but I don't know what the tool is for DNGs of uncorrected negatives.
